# Typescript doing unasked for intersection

Tags: typescript

I have this setup

```js
type MyType = { reason: string };
type OnAccept = (arg0: string) => void;
type OnReject = (arg0: MyType) => void;

const cbAction = (cb: OnAccept | OnReject) => (params: string | MyType) => {
  cb(params);
  // do stuff
};
```

but Typescript is complaining with `Argument of type 'string | MyType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & MyType'`
[image]

I tried this but it didn't work as well

```js
const cbAction = <T extends OnAccept | OnReject>(cb: T) => (params: T extends OnAccept ? string : MyType) => {
  cb(params);
  // do stuff
};
```

How to implement this without the compiler complaining?
Where did the intersection `string & MyType` come from?

Comment: It's a merge of both function signatures. If you say that your function could be either of these, then the code should be ready to call either of these. Yet if you receive an `OnReject` you cannot call it with a string. Nor can you cal an `OnAccept` with a `MyType`. Whatever you get for `param` will not fit one of the function signatures. Therefore, you cannot just call `cb` with `param`

Comment: @VLAZ I see, is there a way in Typescript to solve this?

Comment: The conditional type you have solves this. I'll have a coffee and think if there is anything more elegant. Although, I'd expect somebody who is actually good at TS to have a better suggestion than me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `cbAction` to be a function that gets a parameter `cb` which can be of type `OnAccept` or `OnResult`.  In your function you execute this callback `cb(params)`.
Since we don't know if `cb` is `OnAccept` or `OnResult`, `params` must satisfy both: i.e. `string & MyType`

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8oCcIEMDOA9gHYBcUewmAlkQOZQC%20A3ALABQokUA8kQIIBjARDDAoqABQ5MtAAxkK1OgEpxAPigA3AlQAmrDkh5EAShABWEAWMnS5ZOIkirkG7XoPsBxClAEAjQWAqYgBGcSgJALJeQWFRKAAfYzNLaxcNCTBpHABbPAVKGnpkxyQM9HYoP38snPzlA2qAemaoXQJyYABXADNe9mZ2dk5oAGEcABtJ-xwBAGsI2KERMWTeVKtgA28iX2ioCenZhYjw-CgcIhAd2uVhtl39wOsQogiAHngoCAAPYAgRF0eC6ShKsAQSDUUX8ZCkMnkUHgFXcugqdUweQKSIqaCqNQxWMa%20Na7U6FD6AzYQzYXhewWIEnh9lBxQqdlkygkACIcP4BNziY96W8mRyHJDnOpLgiuXi2NVqth8MQyAByPkCNWDRpAA):
When you hoover over `cb()` you can see the expanded type:
[image]

I guess this is what you want to do:

```js
const cbAction = <T extends string | MyType>(cb: (arg0: T) => void) => (params: T) => {
  cb(params);
  // do stuff
};

cbAction((arg0: string) => arg0)("abc");
cbAction((arg0: MyType) => arg0)({
    reason: 'abc'
});
```